# ChromiumWebBrowser Display top frame

Tags: chromium, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen, webviewchromium

I have a little problem that i cant find any solution for that subject.
I am using Chromiuim C#. A casual load for the webview:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chrome2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

    CefSettings setting = new CefSettings();

    Cef.Initialize(setting);

    chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com/");
    panel1.Controls.Add(chrome);
    chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

The results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtTcF.png)

Now the top regular chrome is cut/missing/not loading this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ3wV.png)

Should it load regularly or should it load by code

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chrome2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

    CefSettings setting = new CefSettings();

    Cef.Initialize(setting);

    chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com/");
    panel1.Controls.Add(chrome);
    chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4738